# Prime Knots and Prime Numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, knot-theory

I have heard that prime knots and prime numbers are somehow related. I can see the obvious relationship, that they are both defined similarly, but is there anything beyond this?

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781447121572

Comment: The book relates knots and primes, but I'd be surprised if there was any specific relation between primes and *prime* knots. Always happy to learn!

Comment: This [MathOverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/50879/what-is-the-knot-associated-to-a-prime) seems relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a comment about composition.  As is well known, every integer can be decomposed into its prime factorization.  So, $12 = 2\times 2 \times 3$.  In the same way, every knot can be decomposed into the simplest pieces that cannot be further decomposed.  We call these pieces [prime knots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_knot).  The knots which can be decomposed we call [composite knots](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompositeKnot.html) and the operation to put them together is called the connected sum or [knot sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KnotSum.html).  See these links for images that will probably help.

The point here is that you can often get away with only looking at prime knots because every composite knot can be broken down.  Otherwise, I don't know of how you would "relate" prime knots and numbers.